# MongoDB Views Sum

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, sum

I have MongoDB object called Article:

```
var articleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title:{
        type:String,
        index:true
    },
    views:{
        type:Number,
    },
    active:{
        type: Boolean
    }

});
```

Now I am trying to get a sum of all articles views.
I tried with this module sample, but it's not working.
What em am I doing wrong?

```
module.exports.visitsCounter = function() {

    Article.aggregate([
        {"$group" : {_id:"$views", count:{$sum:1}}}
    ], function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("View Incremented!"+result.count);
    });
}
```

Comment: you should try to group by `views.type` like this: `{$group: {_id: "$views.type", count: {$sum: 1}}}`

Comment: I tried:     Article.aggregate([
        {"$group" : {_id:"$views.type", count:{$sum:1}}}
    ], function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        console.log("View Incremented!"+result);
    });

Comment: End console log result is:View Incremented![object Object]

Comment: `console.log("View Incremented!"+result[0].count)` So are you actually trying to "update" the data or are you trying to get the totals? Both correcting your syntax error there and asking the question.

Comment: And it's `{ "$group": { "_id": null, "views": { "$sum": "$views } }}` The `result` is in array so you want the `0` index hence `results[0].views`

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you very much!  I just fixed few apostrophes in your line and it works!   { "$group": { "_id": null, "views": { $sum: '$views' } }}   You can add it as correct answer.